# Displaying floats instead of exponentials in statsmodel outputs

Tags: python, format, output, statsmodels, anova

I am running a One-Way Anova using statsmodels, where a group-variable ('age_group') predicts the dependant variable ('score'). I then conduct pairwise t-tests (using t_test_pairwise) to examine between which of the age-groups there were differences in the score.

In my outputs, p-values are displayed as exponentials instead of floats (e.g, 8.702542e-02 instead of 0.008702542) which makes the output table more difficult to read and less presentable.

My output:
[image: output table]

In all example codes I saw, the output table was displayed in floats; I ran the same lines of code and restarted the kernel multiple times; outputs remain in exponentials. Any way of fixing this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to round your result using the builtin function `round(number_to_be_rounded, number_of_digits)`.

However this will lead you to a loss of information, another solution could be to use strings formatted in the correct way, for instance:

```
"{:.10f}".format(p_value)
```

which will print 10 digits after the comma.

In your case, after you called the `t_test_pairwise` function, you should do:

```
pair_t.result_frame["pvalue-hs"].apply(lambda x: "{:.10f}".format(x))
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!

I added your line and received the following TypeError message: 'MultiCompResult' object is not subscriptable

I assume that this is because pair_t is not a proper table? Would there be a way of fixing this (or another way of fixing my problem)?

Comment: Exactly, I forgot to get the pandas DataFrame from the MultiCompResult. I edited my answer, now it should work.